# Argument list too long - lint-staged -> tslint

Tags: git, npm, tslint, npm-scripts, lint-staged

In our project we ran into a weird issue after integrating lint-staged along with prettier and tslint.
The idea was to apply `prettier` and then `tslint` to all files in the commit using `husky` **pre-commit** git hook.

In order for the whole project to conform to the new code styling described by the `prettier`, we decided to first run `prettier` for the whole project and then commit all those files with the git hook described above.

After running `prettier` we ended up with 400+ files to commit. So, when running `git commit` `lint-staged` passed all those 400+ files as arguments to `prettier` and `tslint` scripts.

Originally we had the `tslint` as a script inside `package.json` which looked like the following:

`"lint": "tslint -c tslint.json --project src/tsconfig.json"`

And the `lint-staged` config looked like the following:

```
{
  "linters": {
     "*.ts": ["prettier --write", "npm run lint", "git add"]
  },
  "ignore": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

When we ran `git commit` npm ended up with error at the linting stage. No error description was given in the output.
Then we tried to copy all the file paths lint-staged gave us into the terminal and ran `npm run lint` with all those file paths manually.

The error we had said that `Argument list too long`.

```
sh: /path-to-app/node_modules/.bin/tslint: Argument list too long
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
```

By further trial we figured out that the maximum number of file paths that can be accepted without any errors is 357. So, when we were running the linting script via `npm run lint` we could only pass 357 file paths as arguments maximum.

However, the interesting thing was that if we change the `lint staged` script to use `tslint` straight away (without `npm run lint`):

```
{
   "linters": {
      "*.ts": ["prettier --write", "tslint -c tslint.json --project src/tsconfig.json", "git add"]
   },
   "ignore": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

This error with `Argument list too long` was gone and linting started to work without errors - no matter how many files were passed as arguments.

Thus, the problem itself was solved. But the question stays - what's the reason for such behaviour? Basically, when running scripts with `npm run` we can pass the limited number of arguments while otherwise - no problems occur no matter how many arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limits to the number of parameters and environment variables that you can pass to a new process. These limits come from the kernel itself.

However, if you are on modern Linux x86_64 (likely), this should not be a problem; certainly not with only 357 parameters.

Now, a single parameter cannot be more than 128 KiB in length. If you were passing all the parameters in a single string (which counts as a single argument), you could hit the limit if each of the paths were really big (around 350 characters each).

If that was not the case, then maybe your shell (or some other tool in the chain) has some artificial, more stringent limits.